# C program compiles in xcode, but runs infinite loop in terminal

Tags: c, xcode, macos, terminal, systems-programming

I've been working on a group program for a systems programming class which will run functions that someone at a bank would use.  These functions include add bank customers, output balance of a customer, and so on.  The problem lies with the add customer function.

This function will run in an infinite loop in terminal and Putty, but when I run it as a standalone program in XCode the loop quits.  Is there anything wrong with the program that I, my group members AND our professor are overlooking?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "./bank.h"

void add(FILE *fp)
{
    int i=0;
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
    float camount;
    int prompt;
    float samount;
    float mamount;
    fseek(fp,0,2);
do

{
   printf("\nEnter first name: ");
   scanf("%s", firstName);
   strcpy(bank[i].firstName, firstName);

   printf("\nEnter last name: ");
   scanf("%s",lastName);
   strcpy(bank[i].lastName, lastName);

   printf("\nEnter checking account balance: ");
   scanf("%f", &camount);
   bank[i].checking = camount;

   printf("\nEnter savings account balance: ");
   scanf("%f", &samount);
   bank[i].savings = samount;

   printf("\nEnter money market account balance: ");
   scanf("%f", &mamount);
   bank[i].moneyMarket = mamount;

   fwrite(&bank[i],1, sizeof(struct BankInfo),fp);
   i++;

   printf("Enter 1 to enter another name and 0 to quit: ");
   scanf("%d", &prompt);
   printf("%d\n", prompt);

   } while(prompt == 1);

   fclose(fp);
   return;
}
```

Screenshot of output once Makefile is executed:
[image: screenshot]

Sidenote: This function does write onto the file that we are passing which is great but we still need for it to break out of the loop.

**EDIT:** code for the main function:
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include "bank.h"
    #include "definitions.h"

```
int main()
{
FILE *fp;
int selection;
fp=fopen("bankInfo.dat","ab+");

selection=menu();

while(selection !=6)
{
switch(selection)
{
  case 1:
       add(fp);
       break;

       case 2:
          //  outputBalance(fp);
            break;
      case 3:
            delete(fp);
            break;
      case 4:
            update(fp);
            break;
    case 5:
         // display(fp);
            break;
    case 6:
            exit(0);
            break;
    default:
            printf("Invalid selection\n");
            break;
    }
}
fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that something else that's calling the add function is in a loop ?

Comment: Please show the code where you are calling this `Add` function.

Comment: I just added the main function to my question

Comment: `selection` don't update inside of `while(selection !=6){...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning selection only once. This should fix your issue:

```
while(true)
{
selection=menu();
switch(selection)
{
  case 1:
       add(fp);
       break;

       case 2:
          //  outputBalance(fp);
            break;
      case 3:
            delete(fp);
            break;
      case 4:
            update(fp);
            break;
    case 5:
         // display(fp);
            break;
    case 6:
            fclose(fp);
            exit(0);
            break;
    default:
            printf("Invalid selection\n");
            break;
    }
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Thank you! This has been driving us crazy all day! We asked 3 different professors and none of them could figure it out.

Comment: @ You are right of course. In fact, there is no need to check selection value at all in the loop condition.